# Do I making a bad request to Graph API Facebook?

Tags: django, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a Django REST framework app that allow post images and videos on Facebook. I got several failed attempts when I try to post a video using the Graph API, I've all required permissions such as `pages_show_list` ,  `pages_read_engagement` and `pages_manage_posts` but I can't post anything.

This is the ViewSet that I use for upload a video:

```
class FacebookVideoPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FacebookVideoPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FacebookVideoPostSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            
            # Obtenemos la ruta base del proyecto
            ruta_base = os.path.abspath(settings.BASE_DIR)
            # Obtenemos la ruta relativa en donde está el archivo recién subido
            ruta_video = serializer.data['file']
            # Concatenamos ambas rutas y obtenemos la ruta relativa del archivo que intentaremos subir
            ruta_abs = ruta_base + ruta_video
            # Obtenemos el tamaño en bytes del video
            size_video = os.path.getsize(ruta_abs)
            print(ruta_abs)
            print('Tamaño es bytes: ', size_video)


            try:
                # ======[ FASE 1 ]======
                # 1. Hacemos la petición inicial de la subida reanudable del video
                init_sesion_subida = requests.post(f'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v16.0/{settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID}/videos?upload_phase=start&access_token={settings.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN}&file_size={size_video}')
                # Comprobamos que la petición se haya hecho de forma correcta
                if init_sesion_subida.status_code == 200:

                    # Valores obtenidos al iniciar la sesión de subida
                    # Obtenemos el diccionario que se nos retorno
                    dict_valores_subida = init_sesion_subida.json()
                    # video_id
                    video_id = dict_valores_subida['video_id']
                    # start_offset
                    start_offset = dict_valores_subida['start_offset']
                    # upload_session_id
                    upload_session_id = dict_valores_subida['upload_session_id']

                    # ======[ FASE 2 ]======
                    # 2. Se empiezan a subir los fragmentos individuales
                    # Primero establecemos la cabecera
                    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
                    # Iniciamos la petición de subida de fragmentos
                    req_subida = requests.post(f'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v16.0/{settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID}/videos?upload_phase=transfer&access_token={settings.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN}&upload_session_id={upload_session_id}&start_offset={start_offset}&video_file_chunk={ruta_abs}', headers=headers)

                    # Comprobamos que la petición se haya hecho de forma correcta
                    if req_subida.status_code == 200:
                        # Capturamos los valores de la respuesta
                        dict_val = req_subida.json()
                        # Capturamos el valor end_offset
                        end_offset = dict_val['end_offset']

                        # Comenzamos a subir los fragmentos uno por uno
                        while start_offset < end_offset:
                            frag_subida = requests.post(f'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v16.0/{settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID}/videos?upload_phase=transfer&access_token={settings.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN}&upload_session_id={upload_session_id}&start_offset={start_offset}&video_file_chunk={ruta_abs}', headers=headers)

                            # Comprobamos que el siguiente fragmento se haya subido correctamente
                            if frag_subida.status_code == 200:
                                # Capturamos los valores de la respuesta
                                dict_val = frag_subida.json()
                                # Capturamos el valor de start_offset
                                start_offset = dict_val['start_offset']
                                # Capturamos el valor de end_offset
                                end_offset = dict_val['end_offset']
                            else:
                                # En caso de algún error lo capturamos
                                err = frag_subida.json()
                                raise Exception('Ha ocurrido un error al momento de subir uno de los fragmentos del video.')

                        # ======[ FASE 3 ]======
                        # 3. Finalizamos la sesión de subida
                        end_subida = requests.post(f'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v16.0/{settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID}/videos?upload_phase=finish&access_token={settings.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN}&upload_session_id={upload_session_id}')

                        # Comprobamos que la petición para finalizar la subida haya salida de forma exitosa
                        if end_subida.status_code == 200:
                            return Response({
                            'ok': True,
                            'message': 'El video se ha subido correctamente'
                        })
                        else:
                            raise Exception('Ha ocurrido un error al momento de finalizar la sesión de subida.')

                        
                    else:
                        # En caso de algún error lo capturamos
                        err = req_subida.json()
                        raise Exception('Ha ocurrido un error al momento de subir el primer fragmento del video.')


                else:
                    # En caso de algún error lo capturamos
                    err = init_sesion_subida.json()
                    raise Exception('Ha ocurrido un error al momento de iniciar la subida del video.')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return Response({
                    'ok': False,
                    'server_error': err
                }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            finally:
                pass
```

And this is the response that I get:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "server_error": {
        "error": {
            "message": "Service temporarily unavailable",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "is_transient": true,
            "code": 2,
            "error_subcode": 1363030,
            "error_user_title": "Tiempo de espera agotado al subir el video",
            "error_user_msg": "Se agotó el tiempo de espera antes de que se terminara de subir el video. Probablemente se debe a una conexión de red lenta o a que el video que intentas subir es demasiado grande. Vuelve a intentarlo.",
            "fbtrace_id": "ARcdaiKCc7m5E_GCB5dKE1w"
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how I could to fix this, I'll be so grateful!